# Soft Body physics destroys vertices

Tags: physics, vertices, soft-body

I have two slightly overlapping meshes and I want to use soft body physics solve the overlap between them.

Most of the time this works fine, however I'm finding that occasionally it goes completely wrong. In the attached .blend file, I have an example of two meshes set up with the physics I use and then when I move the animation forward one frame, all of the vertices that can be affected by the simulation just disappear.

[image]

If I do the same thing using a script and save the result to .ply files then I end up with all of those missing vertices placed on the origin, completely destroying the mesh as shown below.

[image]

Any ideas that might resolve this?

Comment: I don't have a very powerful computer, but if you do, try using edge and/or face collisions. I have no clue if it will help or not but there is no reason not to try it.